# sending a file over serial port

Tags: c, linux, file-io, serial-port

using this code, i am trying for sending file to CC430f5137 and receive back from it. I am using 2 programs, one is the below program( it is for sending and receiving back file to my linux VM and other one is program for the CC430f5137(it contains rx, tx code for my device which is in windows). I could able to send a single byte(for ex,A) from a file to my device but not multiple bytes.

```
//sample1.c

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/signal.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <sys/poll.h>
#include <termios.h>
#define BUFSIZE            1300 //1

int open_serial( char *dev_name, int baud, int vtime, int vmin )
{
    int fd;
    struct termios  newtio;

    fd = open( dev_name, O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY );
    if ( fd < 0 )
    {
        printf( "Device OPEN FAIL %s\n", dev_name );
        return  -1;
    }
    memset(&newtio, 0, sizeof(newtio));
    newtio.c_iflag = IGNPAR|INLCR;  // non-parity void UARTHandler(int fd);
    newtio.c_oflag = 0;
    newtio.c_cflag = CS8 | CLOCAL | CREAD; // NO-rts/cts

    switch( baud )
    {
        case 115200 : newtio.c_cflag |= B115200; break;
        case 57600  : newtio.c_cflag |= B57600;  break;
        case 38400  : newtio.c_cflag |= B38400;  break;
        case 19200  : newtio.c_cflag |= B19200;  break;
        case 9600   : newtio.c_cflag |= B9600;   break;
        case 4800   : newtio.c_cflag |= B4800;   break;
        case 2400   : newtio.c_cflag |= B2400;   break;
        default     : newtio.c_cflag |= B115200; break;
    }
    //set input mode (non-canonical, no echo,.....)
    newtio.c_lflag = 0;
    newtio.c_cc[VTIME] = vtime;
    newtio.c_cc[VMIN]  = vmin;
    tcflush  ( fd, TCIFLUSH );
    tcsetattr( fd, TCSANOW, &newtio );

    return fd;
}

int sendfile(int fd)      //void sendfile(int fd)
{
    int fd1,readc;
    unsigned short fileLength;
    unsigned char buf[BUFSIZE];

    fd1=open("cert.pem",O_RDONLY);

    fileLength=lseek(fd1,0,SEEK_END);
    printf("file length is %d bytes\n",fileLength);
    lseek(fd1,0,SEEK_SET);

    write(fd,(unsigned char*)&fileLength, 2);
           while(fileLength>0)
            {
                if(fileLength>=BUFSIZE)
                {
                    readc=read(fd1,buf,BUFSIZE);
                    if(readc==-1)
                    {
                    printf("read failed!!\n");
                    }
                    if(read>0)
                    {
                    buf[BUFSIZE]='\0';
                    printf("%s\n",buf);
                    if(write(fd,buf,BUFSIZE))
                    fileLength -= BUFSIZE;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    readc=read(fd1,buf,fileLength);
                    if(readc==-1)
                    {
                    printf("read failed!!\n");
                    }
                    if(readc>0)
                    {
                    buf[fileLength]='\0';
                    printf("%s\n",buf);
                    if(write(fd, buf, fileLength))
                    fileLength=0;
                    }
                }
            }
    printf("%s\n",fd);
    printf("file sent succssfully\n");
    return fd1;//close(fd1);
    close(fd);

}

void receivefile(int fd)
    {
        char buf[1300],read_byte,buf2[1300];
        int fd2,readc;
        unsigned short fileLength;

        fd2=open("test.pem", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT);

                if(fd2<0)
                {
                printf("file open failed!!\n");
                        }
                while(!(read(fd,(unsigned char*)&fileLength,2)>0));

                printf("i am in receive file\n");

                while(fileLength>0) 
                {
                    readc = read(fd, buf, BUFSIZE);
                    if(readc==-1)
                    {
                    printf("read failed!!\n");
                    }
                printf("read %d bytes, value is %s\n",readc,buf);

                    if(readc >0)
                    {
                    buf[readc]='\0';
                    printf("buf value is%s\n", buf);
                    write(fd2,buf,readc);
                    fileLength -= readc;
                    }
                }
            close(fd2);
            close(fd);
    }

void close_serial( int fd )
{
    close( fd );
    printf("ClosePort!!\n");
}

int  main( int argc, char **argv )
{
    int fd;
    int baud;
    char  dev_name[128];

    if ( argc != 3)
    {
        printf( " sample_serial [device] [baud]\n" \
               "    device : /dev/ttySAC0 ...\n"    \
               "    baud   : 2400 ... 115200\n" );
        return -1;
    }
    printf( " Serial test start...  (%s)\n", __DATE__ );

    strcpy( dev_name, argv[1] );
    baud    = strtoul( argv[2], NULL, 10 );

    fd = open_serial( dev_name, baud, 4, 1);

    sendfile(fd);
    receivefile(fd);        
    close_serial( fd );        
    printf( " Serial test end\n" );

    return  0;
}
```

this is output of sending 1 byte from the file to serial port

```
  [root@localhost ~]# gcc -std=c99 -std=gnu99 sample1.c -o out1
  sample1.c:151:50: warning: backslash and newline separated by space
  sample1.c:152:45: warning: backslash and newline separated by space
  [root@localhost ~]# ./out1 /dev/ttyUSB20 115200
  Serial test start...  (Mar  6 2013)
  file length is 2 bytes
  A
  wrote 3 bytes
  file sent succssfully
  i am in receive file
  read 1 bytes, value is A
  buf value isA
  read 1 bytes, value is A
  buf value isA
  read 1 bytes, value is A
  buf value isA
  read 1 bytes, value is A
  buf value isA
```

this is output of sending multiple bytes from the file to serial port

```
  [root@localhost ~]# gcc -std=c99 -std=gnu99 sample1.c -o out1
  sample1.c:151:50: warning: backslash and newline separated by space
  sample1.c:152:45: warning: backslash and newline separated by space
  [root@localhost ~]# ./out1 /dev/ttyUSB20 115200
  Serial test start...  (Mar  6 2013)
  file length is 2 bytes
  i am doing well today
  wrote 3 bytes
  file sent succssfully
  i am in receive file
  read 1 bytes, value is
  buf value is
  read 1 bytes, value is 
  buf value is
  read 1 bytes, value is 
  buf value is
  read 1 bytes, value is 
  buf value is
```

As you see here, i am not getting file contents, i am receving null characters back
  from my device, even though i sent multiple bytes to my device.

sendfile() is working properly,i can able to write "cert.pem" to port.I have a
  problem with reading file from port and writing back to "test.pem".I am getting output of
  some print statement given in the receiver program, but getting data    continuously.flagsettings are in a
  proper way. I have reset all connections also.

Comment: That's a lot of code for us to read… Can you be more specific about what works and does not work? Maybe only show only the relevant parts of your code?

Comment: Serial ports can be hairy wee beasts.  It's not productive for you to post your code and ask us to tell you why "it doesn't work".  You should start by doing some basic investigation on your own.  Take the code for connection and test that it works.  Check that all the port flags are set correctly.  Try to send and receive single bytes.  Test that your files are being opened and read correctly.  Test that the receiving end can create the file.

Comment: And on the above note...  I notice that you never check whether your file handles are valid when you open `test.pem`.

Comment: What is the purpose of `while(!(read(fd,(unsigned char*)&fileLength,2)>0));`? This doesn't actually gain you anything at all and if read returns `-1` (error), it actually hurts you - you loop forever. [man read](http://linux.die.net/man/2/read)

Comment: libcurl ??? http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/

Comment: reason for using while(!(read(fd,(unsigned char*)&fileLength,2)>0)); condition is, this C program in linux will wait at the terminal until it receive a character back from my application code.

Comment: thank you for your replies. I did a few changes on the code. Sendfile() is working properly now. I want to receive back the file.Would you please tell me about problem in receiving. I am also getting reply from receiver, where i have some print statements, but not getting the file back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start with the obvious.

a : `Sendfile` doesn't have any looping construct in it...

b: buffer overruns, like this:

```
unsigned char buf[BUFSIZE];
...
buf[BUFSIZE]=0
```

c: You have debug like this 'read 1 bytes, value is A' but it's not in the code. Difficult to fix code you haven't posted...

Comment: thank you.Could you please tell me a bit more?I am able to write file on port. But not able to receive back into file test.pem. I missed a line in code before(as you said).I have edited code.

Comment: @aparna : a: when you send a file longer than one buffer, you'll need a loop (`for` or `while`) like you have in your receive code. *Buffer overruns*. C array indexes go from  0 to n-1, so buf[BUFSIZE] is writing outside your array and corrupting something else.

Answer (score 2):

You are doing it wrong - instead of re-inventing a solution to the problem of sending binary file over serial links, use the already existing standard solutions, such as  [ZMODEM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZMODEM)

When you do, you wont have to write the Linux side program, since a free program to this already exists and you would be able to port an existing program to your CC430f5137, whatever that is.

Comment: Thank you.specifically,i am sending a file(certificate,to test authentication) of microcontroller, file is generated using open source code in linux Virtual Machine.I am sending file to other open source code( this code is designed to run on microcontrollers) in windows.Please let me know your respose now. are you saying about this case?

Comment: I'm saying that you need to use existing libraries and protocols, such as ZMODEM. This will save you coding and debugging time.